# Edit props value of an child component directly in the component tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button with the library element.io :

```
<el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit()" icon="el-icon-check" :loading="false">Sauvegarder</el-button>
```

I have a lot of buttons like this on my app and i want to change loading to true on click.

I know i can do `:loading="loading_button1"` and change it on submit but it's not a proper way.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create an array called `loadings` which contains the initial loading state of each button as follow:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    loadings: {
    1:false,
     2:false,
      3:false,
       4:false
    }
    
  },
  methods:{
     onSubmit(){}
  }
})
```

```css
#example{
padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<!-- import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<!-- import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id='example'>
 <el-button type="primary" @click="loadings[1]=true" icon="el-icon-check" :loading="loadings[1]">Sauvegarder</el-button>
  <el-button type="primary" @click="loadings[2]=true" icon="el-icon-check" :loading="loadings[2]">Sauvegarder</el-button>
  <el-button type="primary" @click="loadings[3]=true" icon="el-icon-check" :loading="loadings[3]">Sauvegarder</el-button>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="loadings[4]=true" icon="el-icon-check" :loading="loadings[4]">Sauvegarder</el-button>
</div>
```